# Zend path to file issue

Tags: file, zend-framework, path, zend-framework3

I'm having some troubles with the path of a file with Zend 3 (I'm a beginner).

The file I want to read is `/public/data/csv_data.csv`, and I would like to access it from a model (`Module/Map/src/Model/Map.php`). I have tried different paths but impossible to get the right one since yesterday... Do you have any ideas ?
(see project directory below)

The vhost (I'm using wamp) is set to the root of the project, geolocalisation, so the url of the index is geolocalisation/skeleton-application/public, if that changes anything to the problem.

[image: Project directory]

Thanks all

Jules

Comment: `$file = getcwd() . '/data/' . $fileName`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`public/data/csv_data.csv` is probably the correct path. Code runs relative to the application root (this: https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication/blob/master/public/index.php#L10 is what makes that happen).

Otherwise, please update your question to include paths you've tried and what errors you got from each attempt.

Comment: I get " Warning: file(public/data/csv_data.csv): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp64\www\geolocalisation\skeleton-application\module\Map\src\Model\Map.php on line " with public/data/csv_data.csv

Comment: The filename shown in your screenshot is `demo_data.csv` - could that be the problem? Try `public/data/demo_data.csv` as the path.

Comment: My god.. that was the problem.

Comment: @Jules R - we've all been there!